# Why are key agents sometimes preferred over configuration files?

Tags: ssh, security, git

Some programs seem to prefer to use an SSH key agent, rather than specifying the key file in some configuration file somewhere.

Examples:

- [GitHub's instructions for using SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)
- [SourceTree's method for using SSH](https://deedoubleewedee.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/setting-up-ssh-keys-for-a-git-repository-using-sourcetree-and-bitbucket/)

What is the reasoning for using a key agent, rather than pointing each application at a file containing your key?  Is there a security difference, or is it just for convenience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several advantages in using `ssh-agent` against letting `ssh` to use the key directly:

- **comfort**: You add your passphrase-protected key into the agent and then you can do whatever you like (`push`, `ssh`, `rsync`)
- **security**: Handling private keys in separate process is good way to avoid security bugs in `ssh`. For example because of recent *CVE-2016-0777* and *CVE-2016-0778*, malicious server could read your decrypted private keys from your client.

On the other hand, there are things that can't be done using only agent and `ssh_config` works fine in cooperation with `ssh-agent`, especially if you have more identities on the single server with different keys.